# Is there evidence that non-profits might have a tax or other competitive advantage in competing with for-profit corporations?

Tags: competition, taxation, climate-change

Lets say my non-profit's interest is to diminish co2 emissions in the city.
Are there useful forms of putting that tax money for better use and gaining competitive advantage against other for-profit car companies?

Comment: What if I edit and leave just the second part of the question?

Comment: I'll edit, thanks.

Comment: Which country are you thinking of?